# Adding new node to a scalable system with zero downtime

Tags: java, cloud, distributed-computing

I am working as a developer on a batch processing solution, how it works is that we split a big file and process it across jvms. So we have 4 processor jvms which take a chunk of file and process it and 1 gateway jvm job of gateway jvm is to split the file into no. of processor jvms i.e. 4 and send a rest request which is consumed by processor jvms, rest request has all the details the file location it has to pick the file from and some other details

Now if i want to add another processor jvm without any downtime is there any way we can do it. Currently we are maintaining the urls for 4 jvms in a property file is there any better way to do it ? which provided me the ability to add more jvms without restarting any component

Comment: _"Currently we are maintaining the urls for 4 jvms in a property file"_ -- that is primitive and hard to scale.  The architecture you are looking for is _Message Queues_, like JMS or IBM MQ (or whatever it's called nowadays) or any of several other products.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider setting up a load balancer and putting your JVM(s) behind it. The load balancer would be responsible for distributing the incoming requests to the JVMs.

This way you can scale up or scale down your JVM depending on the work load. Also, if one of the JVMs are not working, other part of your system need not care about it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your use case and tech stack you are following. But it seems that you need to have distributed system with auto-scaling and dynamic provisioning capabilities. Have you considered Hadoop or Spark clusters or Akka?

If you can not use any of it, then solution is to maintain list of JVMs in some datastore (lets say in a table); its dynamic data meaning one can add/remove/update JVMs. Then you need a resource manager who can decide whether to spin up a new JVM based on load or any other conditional logic. This resource manager needs to monitor entire system. Also, whenever you create a task or chunk or slice data then distribute it using message queues such as ApacheMQ, ActiveMQ. You can also consider Kafka for complex use cases. Now a days, application servers such as websphere (Libery profile), weblogic also provide auto-scaling capability. So, if you are already using any of such application server then you can think of making use of that capability. I hope this helps.